# Sample rest url to retrieve content from alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I want to retrieve content of sample.html inside catalog folder in alfresco using restful.

From alfresco document i got the following rest url to retrieve content of a document. But i dont know exactly what is property, `stor_type`, `store_id`,`id` and `attach`.

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/node/content{property}/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}?a={attach?}
```

It would be grateful if someone explains me the above rest url properties and provide me a example.

Comment: Why the downvote? Although the question is quite localized, the problem is very general (that the documentation for the Alfresco REST API is very minimal and doesn't have many (any?) examples). The [relevant page on the wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference) has no examples for this particular API, for example (although it does explain what `attach` means).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [CMIS Web Scripts Reference](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference) and the [Repository RESTful API Reference](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference) give a little more information (but no examples).

- `property` is the property of the node to follow in order to obtain the content - this will default to `cm:content` so can generally be omitted
- `store_type` will normally be "workspace" for live application data - see [this forum discussion](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?t=63) on store types etc
- `store_id` will be "SpacesStore" for normal files - see [this forum discussion](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?t=10459) on other stores
- `id` is the unique identifier for the node (within a given store), e.g. `986b162e-0867-4a7b-9f4f-0e3837cdc97b`
- `attach`  - if true, force download of content as attachment (defaults to false) - I think this is to trigger "Save as..." in a browser rather than directly streaming the content?

Example GET URL (untested - and of course you'd need to use a valid host, port and `id`)

```
http://my.example.com:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/986b162e-0867-4a7b-9f4f-0e3837cdc97b
```

Together, the `store_type`, `store_id` and `id` form a `NodeRef` which [uniquely identifies a node](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/NodeRef_cookbook), e.g.

```
workspace://SpacesStore/f1a5e908-80cb-4c6e-b919-cc80fe53b835
```

There are a couple of examples (though not of this exact API call) on Jeff Potts' [tutorial on Curl and web scripts](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2009/04/10/959).

If you want to download a file by name and path (without already knowing the node ID) then you will need to use another API, as the one you are using requires you to know the node ID.

[This page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/URL_Addressability#DownloadContentServlet) mentions a direct download URL that accepts a path and filename, e.g.

```
/alfresco/download/direct?path=/Company%20Home/My%20Home%20Space/myimage.jpg
```

Depending on access controls, you may need to add the [login ticket](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/URL_Addressability#Ticket_URL_Argument) parameter to this URL, e.g. `&alf_ticket=1234567890`, where `1234567890` is the security ticket provided by the [login URL](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Login).

---

Note: although I refer to the CMIS Web Scripts Reference above, see also [this posting](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=46473) and [Jira ticket](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-12667) that state that CMIS web script URLs are deprecated, i.e. ( `/alfresco/service/cmis` and `/alfresco/cmis`)

Comment: Just a note that the CMIS web script URLs have been deprecated because the OpenCMIS servlet now shipped in the repository webapp provides an improved experience - as noted on the forum post which you linked to.